# How to add NATIVE ads from admob?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

i saw in some old videos that they found here an option called Native to add new unit for native ads but i did not find it on mine!!

**PLEASE HELP ME !! what need i to do to add a native ads using kotlin code ?**

[image]

Comment: There is literally a button which will take you to a detailed tutorial, right on your screenshot...

Comment: i want to create native ad unit and i don't see this option brother !!

Comment: Oh, I see. I am afraid that there is no such a thing, becasue `Native ads take on the format or tone of the website they show on, with the goal of a seamless user experience`. It's just a styling type, not a type of dialog etc

Comment: so how can i add a nativ ads to my app ?

Answer (score 1):

Google provides an article on how it is done.

[Check it out](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-unified) and see if it helps.

As for the Unit ID, you will need to generate it from Admob's dashboard.

You can get a generat idea on how to do it following [Admob's guide](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6231370?hl=en&ref_topic=6162738)

Next time, make sure you do a quick search. This was the very first result from Google when querying "Android Native Ads"

Comment: yes brother i saw that but i did not understand where i found the adUnit for nativ adfs

Comment: Oh, do you mean the string id you obtain from admob?
As far as I know, any unit id will work, even if it is one you do not own.

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("DEVICE_ID")
        .build();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

In Xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="Your ID"
ads:adSize="320x150">
```

Comment: brother my problem is in findind the adUnitID i don't now where to generated ?

Comment: you can find it in logcat..check logcat